# Send an ajax request only after the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I am using microsoft asp.net mvc for server side of my application and using jquery for client side.
In my application I need to to do some thing when a specific page is loaded. I need to send a request to server side and do some thing. Because I do this in client side, every user can see my request, I want to be sure that the user which made the request is not the one that request the specific page. So far I use the request forgery token, But for the past month I track the exception and errors which my application faced, I see the the required anti-forgery cookie "myCookieName" is not present. First if some one can tell me what it is my mistake, and second if some one can suggest another solution.

This is my html code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Id)
}
```

This is my java script code:

```
(function() {
$(function() {
    var $form = $("#myForm");
    $form.ajaxSubmit({
        success: function () {
            $form.remove();
        },
        error: function() {
            $form.remove();
        }
    });
});
}());
```

And this is my MVC code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Action(int id)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You ajax does not include AntiForgery Token

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        var $form = $('#myForm');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', $form).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
                someValue: 'some value' 
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.someValue);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: no if you see i use the ajaxSubmit which is from the jquery library from the link http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ , this lib automatically send the input from the html to controller. tnx for your answer , but this is not my issue.